# Is super() the only code that can be implicit inserted in constructors if needed?

Tags: java

I am trying to understand the Java compiler a little bit about the constructors. I know there are lots of topics about the super keyword in Java.

My main focus aspect of super key word in this question are:

> Does the Java compiler implicitly generates some other constructors apart from
> default one (`super()`), for example: `super(args1, args2)`?

and can this statement be true?

> I am 100% sure that super() is the only code that the Java compiler will insert to a constructor if the constructor does not have super or this in the first statement?

Comment: This question is somewhat misleading, in my opinion. Things in the bytecode do not always neatly correspond one to another and some concepts exist in the bytecode that do not at all exist in the code. And, of course, the compiler does not actually alter your code - it understands that, on the bytecode side, a superconstructor call is required in order for the code to work, and assumes it to be implicit unless it is explicit. Which is not the same thing, even though it might look like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to your question:

> "Does Java compiler has cases that it implicit inserts something else
> like super(args1, args2) in constructors?"

**Ans**:- No, you need to add manually.

> "I am 100% sure that super() is the only code that the Java compiler
> will insert to a constructor if the constructor does not have super or
> this in the first statement"?

**And**:- default constructor of the parent class is implicit added by the compiler. If it required and not present.

Please read line by line details provided in the link of [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Comment: "If it required and not present." - To clarify: A superconstructor call is *always* required, and the only cases where it is not automatically added are when the first statement is a call to a) a superconstructor or b) another constructor of the same class (which then is responsible for calling the superconstructor).

Comment: I will say YES. Because the main purpose of constructor is to initialize the instances of that class and will do for super classes.

Answer (score 6):

Compiler will, by default, generate a call to `super()` constructor within your sub-class constructor, as a first statement, and that's the only thing it will implicitly do for you regarding your question.

If the super-class doesn't have a default constructor, then you must explicitly call to a whichever constructor is available for you (and which you wish among available ones) in the constructor of your subclass.